# Samba-tool ImportError: No module named samba.netcmd.main

Tags: samba

Installed lastest samba(with all dependencies) version 4.12.3 on CentOS 8. I wget samba in /root/ directory and made ./configure without any options and after make && make install samba installed in /root/samba-4.12.3/

When i try to run:

```
/root/samba-4.12.3/bin/samba-tool domain provision --help
```

I have a error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/root/samba-master/bin/samba-tool", line 33, in <module>
 from samba.netcmd.main import cmd_sambatool
ImportError: No module named samba.netcmd.main
```

Tried to export pythonpath:

```
export PYTHONPATH=:/root/samba-4.12.3/bin
```

Also tested with echo $PYTHONPATH path was /root/samba-4.12.3/bin

What can be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to download samba to /usr/local and then do ./configure and after make && make install you have to export python with

```
export PATH=/usr/local/samba/bin/:/usr/local/samba/sbin/:$PATH
```

and after export it is possible to make samba-tool domain provision --help

[link](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Build_Samba_from_Source) section "Adding Samba Commands to the $PATH Variable"

Answer (score 0):

I have just faced the same issue, and the solution was apply below config:

```
$ cd /samba/path
$ ./configure --sbindir=/sbin/
```

**Reference:**
5.2.2 Installation Directories
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Build_Samba_from_Source#Installation_Directories

Above config is not included on Package Dependencies Required to Build Samba.

Package Dependencies Required to Build Samba
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 / CentOS 7 / Scientific Linux 7
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Package_Dependencies_Required_to_Build_Samba#Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_7_.2F_CentOS_7_.2F_Scientific_Linux_7_2